# Optimizar update en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Como podría optimizar mas esta query de update, ya que tengo que actualizar 200,000 registros y la sesión de oracle se termina y no puedo actualizar nada, ni colocándole ROWNUM

Me sale el error: ORA-00028: your session has been killed

```
UPDATE TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD_PSTVS P
SET P.PLAZA = (SELECT T.NOMCAS FROM TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD2_TEST T WHERE T.SEQ=P.SEQ)
WHERE P.NUM_DEC IN ('E422') AND P.PLAZA IS NULL AND  ROWNUM <=10000
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: faltan indices, falta espacio de proceso? 200000 registros no son nada...

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el `EXPLAIN PLAN`.

Comment: @Sal ya he agregado el explain plan

Comment: agrega indices, son todos full scan...

Comment: @gbianchi como puedo agregarlos, casi no se mucho de Oracle

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11722 y si no, seguro tu ide tiene formas mas comodas de hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD_PSTVS  P
USING (
SELECT   T.NOMCAS,
         T.SEQ, 
        T.DEC_EXT
            FROM TMP_IOP_AJUSTE_TRF_RCBD2_TEST T
            WHERE T.DEC_EXT IN ('E422') AND T.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO IN ('24032020.xlsx')
      ) T
       ON (T.SEQ = P.SEQ AND P.NUM_DEC = T.DEC_EXT )
       WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET P.PLAZA= T.NOMCAS
       WHERE P.NUM_DEC IN ('E422') AND P.PLAZA IS NULL AND P.NOMBRE_ARCHIVO IN ('24032020.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer te faltan índices, por lo menos:

```
CREATE INDEX indx_rcbd_pstvs_nd ON tmp_iop_ajuste_trf_rcbd_pstvs(num_dec);
CREATE INDEX indx_rcbd2t_seq ON tmp_iop_ajuste_trf_rcbd2_test(seq);
```

Aquí el detalle es que por cada registro en `P` se realiza la subconsulta; a reserva de saber cómo es la relación de `seq` entre `P` y `T` puedes reducir el tiempo de ejecución con un `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO tmp_iop_ajuste_trf_rcbd_pstvs p
  USING tmp_iop_ajuste_trf_rcbd2_test t
    ON t.seq = p.seq
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET p.plaza = t.nomcas
    WHERE p.num_dec in ('E422')
      AND p.plaza is null
```

Comment: ORA-30926: no se ha podido obtener un juego de filas estable en las tablas de origen

Comment: Necesitamos que expliques la relación de `seq`.